# pass state from parent to child in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

there I'm trying to pass a piece of state from parent to my child,
this is my code

this is the state I want to pass in my child component

```
basicDocumentInformation: {
            month: null,
            days: null,
            hours: 8,
            firstDay:null,
            lastDay:null
        },
```

this is the prop I have in the child component

```
 props: { 
    basicDocumentInformation:{
        required:true
    }
},
```

I want to pass the hours and days because I want to do some calculations on my Ag Grid.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: I dont know how to get these hours and days, in my ag grid so I can calculate these, 

sorry maybe im not giving you enough information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your parent template you just need to pass the data to your child component like this:

```
<MyChildComponent :basicDocumentInformation="basicDocumentInformation" />
```